# User Field that shows user Photo in SharePoint 2013

Tags: list, 2013, field-definition

I have a list definition with Field of type **User**. I need to display a user's photo alongside with his name. In order to do that I'm using **ShowField="NameWithPicture"** attruibute like so:

```
<Field Name="Employee" ID="{33c2ee31-2927-4de3-8e7d-cc1f2676378b}" DisplayName="Name" Type="User" Required="TRUE" UserSelectionMode="PeopleOnly" UserSelectionScope="0" ShowField="NameWithPicture" />
```

Unfortunately in SharePoint 2013 there seems to a problem with the resulting markup:

[image]

[image]

Did anyone manage to do this task in SP 2013, please? Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, we've managed to find a good solution. So, basically, in SharePoint 2013, instead of

```
<Field Name="Employee" ID="{33c2ee31-2927-4de3-8e7d-cc1f2676378b}" DisplayName="Name" Type="User" Required="TRUE" UserSelectionMode="PeopleOnly" UserSelectionScope="0" ShowField="NameWithPicture" />
```

you need to use

```
<Field Name="Employee" ID="{33c2ee31-2927-4de3-8e7d-cc1f2676378b}" DisplayName="Name" Type="User" Required="TRUE" UserSelectionMode="PeopleOnly" UserSelectionScope="0" ShowField="NameWithPictureAndDetails" />
```

Notice **ShowField** attribute

No C# development needed, and no JavaScript crutches.

I hope it helps someone!

**Update**

I've noticed that this problem occurs when you don't include JSLink node inside schema.xml in a View:

```
<JSLink>clienttemplates.js</JSLink>
```

This happenes when you upgrade Visual Studio Solution with SharePoint projects from 2010 to 2013 version.

[image: schema.xml file for your list template]

Answer (score 1):

This might be of some use.

Try to get the user profile using `UserProfileManager`. Then using `GetProfileValueCollection(PropertyConstants.PictureUrl)` you can get the image url of the user.

Comment: Thank you, Sane. So far I'm trying to use out-of-the box feature that allows me to show user profile picture without using C#.